# Plot multiple attributes from rows/columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

See my data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'house_number':['House 1']*6+['House 2']*6
                  ,'room_type':['Master Bedroom', 'Bedroom 1', 'Bedroom 2', 'Kitchen',
                               'Bathroom 1', 'Bathroom 2']*2
                  ,'square_feet':[250,180,150,200,25,30,300,170,175,210,30,20]})

   house_number       room_type  square_feet
0       House 1  Master Bedroom          250
1       House 1       Bedroom 1          180
2       House 1       Bedroom 2          150
3       House 1         Kitchen          200
4       House 1      Bathroom 1           25
5       House 1      Bathroom 2           30
6       House 2  Master Bedroom          300
7       House 2       Bedroom 1          170
8       House 2       Bedroom 2          175
9       House 2         Kitchen          210
10      House 2      Bathroom 1           30
11      House 2      Bathroom 2           20
```

[Data Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9xuR.png)

I'm very new to programming. I'm using Jupyter Notebook and Pandas/matplotlib to plot some data. How would I be able to make a bar chart from this table where the x axis would be room_type and the y axis would be square feet. I only want to plot the data for House 1. I haven't been able to find anything online where I can select only that data from a particular column that matches with a particular value in another column. Does that make sense?

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can do it by filtering the dataframe first then calling plot:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'house_number':['House 1']*6+['House 2']*6
                  ,'room_type':['Master Bedroom', 'Bedroom 1', 'Bedroom 2', 'Kitchen',
                               'Bathroom 1', 'Bathroom 2']*2
                  ,'square_feet':[250,180,150,200,25,30,300,170,175,210,30,20]})

ax = df.query('house_number == "House 1"').plot.bar(x='room_type', y='square_feet')
ax.set_title('House 1')
ax.set_ylabel('square ft')
```

Output:

[image]

Or, you can filter the dataframe using boolean indexing:

```
df[df['house_number'] == 'House 1'].plot.bar(x='room_type', y='square_feet')
```

Comment: Yes! That clears things up immensely. The only difference in what I am doing is I imported this data in a CSV and set it to a variable. I'm not working directly with dictionary & lists, so your last bit of code is perfect! I was not aware of simply filtering a column with a boolean check. Thank you!!!